# validate form using php then post data to external url

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

I have been provided an html form by a 3rd party company to place on my site. The form data is posted to their database via a url they provided.I have applied various javascript validation and anti-spam methods to the form but some spammer script is getting past these measures and writing this data to the database.

I need to somehow intercept the form data on my end and validate using php, and then submnit the data using the url provided.. can you please suggest a way to do this?

This is an issue I've been struggling with for weeks so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Implement a `CAPTCHA`

Answer (score 0):

Post form data to your own page validate it and then post to company URL via CURL in PHP

helpful link. http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post

Note: you need to enable curl in your php.ini file if it is not already enabled.

Comment: ... or if you do not want to use curl, you can do it also with a socket connection by building up your own HTTP 1.1 header, or simply with file_put_contents. Your filename is the url and your data is the HTTP 1.1 header information + your POST data